# Find duplicate numbers without select

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text I know I can find duplicate numbers in my code if I select one by one, but how can I find duplicate numbers without having to select one by one?

Example:

In my code there are many occurrences of the words "Text" and "Number", I would like the sublime to show how many occurrences it has of each word or to mark all duplicate words without having to select any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the Ctrl + d shortcut you need?

Highlight one instance of the text you want to find, and press Ctrl + d and it'll select the next instance of that text, then press Ctrl + d again and it'll select the next one too.

Alternatively, you can just the find (Ctrl + f) function, and press "Find All"

Answer (score -1):

```
finder_logic = random.randint(0,5)
finder_logic2=random.randint(0,5)
rabbit = numbers[finder_logic]
turtle=numbers[finder_logic2]
if finder_logic == finder_logic2:
    finder_logic2=random.randint(3,5)
 if turtle==rabbit:
      print('the duplicated  number is  ' ,turtle)
       break
 if turtle != rabbit:
       print('no duplication found ')
```